# What is a "public" keyword , is it a type?

Tags: c#, oop

[According to Eric](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/07/what-is-this-thing-you-call-a-quot-type-quot-part-two.aspx) "a type in C# is a mathematical entity that obeys certain algebraic rules".

Now the question is what is "public" keyword in c# (besides the usage that public is a keyword used on class , field and delegate by which there accessibility for outside world is defined as accessible) ?

Similar questions can go  like what is "var" key word , is it a type in c# of some type?

If they are type then what algebraic rules do they follow ?

EDIT : May be this question is misinterpreted and I got ban on posting the question. 
Looking forward for someone to lift the ban.
I was confused when I read "Everything is type in any language"

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: Spending even a tiny amount of effort Googling this or reading chapter 1 of any C# book will answer these questions.

Comment: If you have any line of reasoning that leads to "public" being a type, please elaborate.

Comment: Can any of you say with confidance - var  / public is a "type in c#" ?  if yes then according to Eric , what the algebraic rules does it follow ?

Comment: @phoog - What i want to find it out from here is that what is not a type in c# ? "namespace", "access modifiers" , "class" , "Object" , "delegate", "event" ....what not...

Comment: we cannot say that var or public is a type, because *they are not types!*  Therefore, they do not follow algebraic rules.

Comment: namespace, access modifier, the "class" keyword, object instances, delegate instances, events: not a type.  Classes, the "Object" class, delegate types: types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public` is really just an access modifier used, as you already know, on classes, fields etc.

The `var` keyword on the other hand is a shortcut for "whatever type the statement on the right returns". This is really just compiler candy, as it will be resolved to a concrete type (e.g. `Int32`) during compilation.

EDIT: If you are interested in what is a type and what is not, then you might want to have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et.aspx. It will answer the first part of the question explicitly.

Comment: but then Is "Var" a type in c# ?

Comment: @dnkulkarni no. var is not a type.

Comment: Like phoog said, it is not. It is an alias that resolves to a concrete type (i.e. the one to the right). If you write `var number = 42`, then it is equivalent to `int number = 42`: The type of `number` is `Int32`, in both cases - it simply depends on the statement at the right. (Consequently, `int` also is a keyword that resolves to the type `Int32`)

Comment: (To add to the confusion, `dynamic` seems to behave like `var` but is a type indeed; The difference is that `dynamic` is a special runtime evaluated type while `var` is resolved and nailed into the code as soon as you write the closing semicolon.)

Answer (score 0):

The word **Public** is an access Modifier that defines the accessibility of an object or a class.
Public- it refers that it is available through out .